# "ScreenUpdating = False" Not Working for Headers/Footers

Tags: .net, vb.net, ms-word, vsto, add-in

I am building a Word Add-In using VSTO (in VB) and I have a pretty annoying problem. I want to turn off ScreenUpdating while I remove all the Content Controls in every story of my document. So I do the following:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 'loop through all open documents
For Each thisDoc As Word.Document In gbl_docList

   'loop through all stories in each doc
    For Each thisStoryRange As Word.Range In thisDoc.StoryRanges 

        thisDoc.Activate() 'active this doc so we can work on it
        thisStoryRange.Select() 'select the range

        'remove all Content Controls
        For Each thisCC As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ContentControl In thisStoryRange.ContentControls
            thisCC.Delete() 'remove this CC
        Next 'next CC

    Next 'next story

Next 'next doc

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

However, whenever Word loops through the Header or Footer stories, it starts opening a panel at the bottom of the screen and showing that to the user which causes awkward flickering. If there are no Headers/Footers, everything works perfectly.

**QUESTIONS:**

1. Has anyone encountered this problem? Any suggestions?
2. As an alternate solution, is there any way to minimize/hide the Word document within Word but keep the Word window open? I have only been able to find ways to minimize/hide all of Word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that, especially in later versions of Office, the ScreenUpdating setting failed to work in various ways (you'll notice that Ribbon Controls keep updating for instance from Bold to normal depending on the selected text in your procedure, or as you did when handling Headers/Footers)

I reported this way back in 2014, and it was provided to the Office team but (as far as I have seen) was never solved. I still have the mail in my archive with the repro and even a video with that. The repro was based on this demo code:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197438(v=office.15).aspx

The only alternative is to either Minimize MS Word before processing and restoring its size when done, or make MS Word completely invisible (you can show a dialog while processing with some progress if it is a time consuming feature) and restore visibility when done.